# Updating rails to 4.1.11(at ruby 2.1) fails because of minitest 5.13.0(requires ruby 2.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, minitest, activesupport

I have `ruby 2.1` installed and I am trying to upgrade rails to `4.1.11` from `3.2.21`.
Rails [4.1.11](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.1.11) needs `ruby >= 1.9.3`. When i run `bundle install`, it fails saying `'minitest requires Ruby version ~> 2.2'`.

[image]

If rails has minitest(which needs 2.2 of ruby) as a dependency, why does it say that it needs only ruby `>= 1.9.3` ?

Minitest `5.12.0` doesnot require ruby `2.2`. Is there a way to make rails use that version of minitest?

In my gemfile, i just have `gem 'rails', '3.2.21'`

Comment: "why does it say that it needs only ruby 1.8.11"? -- There is no such thing as ruby v1.8.11. There's 1.8.7, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0, ... Anyway, I'm speculating, but presumably the **rails** version - in isolation - worked with a lower ruby version, but a dependency does not.

Comment: Please share the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: My bad. It was ```>= 1.9.3```. I pasted the version of rubygems. I have edited the question.

Comment: I'll repeat myself: Can you please share the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`? I don't know why your project is loading those gem versions without seeing a dependency tree; I can only speculate. In particular, according to that screenshot, `activesupport v4.1.11` only depends on `minitest ~>5.1` -- so there's no reason why it should be "forcing" you to use `5.13.0`, given that it's incompatible with the ruby version. Furthermore, your `Gemfile` cannot contain `gem 'rails', '3.2.21'` -- that must be what the `Gemfile` *used to* contain. Please show the *current* state of both files.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Still a problem in 2020 for those of us dealing with legacy ruby and rails code...

Comment: @MattWest Sorry for the late reply. 

Instead of spending time to solve this, i decided to upgrade ruby to 2.6.5 and rails to 6. I had to make a lot of code changes, but it helped in getting rid of most of the vulnerable Gem versions.